# wp_get_attachment_image_src() and custom sizes

Tags: post-thumbnails

[As said in this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`only accepts built-in sizes such as thumbnail, medium, large or full.

How do you get the same return value with custom sizes you add with `add_image_sizes()` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misreading the Codex. `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` works just fine with custom image sizes.

Proof of concept:

```
// copied from the Codex
// https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300, 9999 ); //300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true ); //(cropped)
}
```

Add an image to the Library, then...

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 28, 'category-thumb' ); 
var_dump($image_attributes);
```

You will notice that the image returned is (an appromixation of) 300x9999-- that is 300 wide by whatever height scales correctly.

Comment: thanks but that is not a proof, I'm already var_dump things to see it. Get nothing but the original thumbs. Guess the truth is elsewhere, I'm on wp beta 3.9 3, do not know if that matters

Comment: Works when I try it and there is [nothing in the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L509) that I see that would limit the sizes. The problem you are having does not lie where you think it does, I am pretty sure.  Tested on 3.9.

Comment: I guess you're right I do not see that too. `$size` is a string.

Comment: But it's weird it workw only with built-in sizes for me !

Comment: There is something else wrong. Try with a bundled theme and no plugins.

Comment: I add +1 for your answer because I think you're right but the problem is still there. When I var_dump I get a false for the fourth element of the array oO

Comment: The fourth element is "`[3] => boolean`: `true` if `$url` is a resized image, `false` if it is the original." I fail to see why that is relevant. Secondly, I believe that are experiencing the problem you describe but this does answer the question as asked and there is no way to guess at what else might be breaking things.

Comment: I already know that because I'm focusing on this particular element of the array but thank you. The chase here is that the $size param of `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` is a $var in my code.

Comment: If that part of the output is the problem, then your question is extremely misleading.

Comment: I thought it was a bug of WP before asking here ^^

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with the specific content of that fourth array element.

Comment: this fourth element shows if it's a resized image or not so indeed it has everything to do with it. But as I said big thanks and sorry to bother you with my stupid questions ^^

Comment: Remember you need to regenerate all thumbnails in order for the new custom size to work. You can do this with code or with the plugin "Regenerate thumbnails".